# Hibernate 3 Annotation Mapping Issue

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am new to Hiberante 3. I am facing issues when I am trying to map three tables with the relations below:

```
ITEM_MASTER (Table):
ITEM_ID-PK
LOCATION_ID

ITEM_MASTER_ATTR (Table):
ITEM_ID - FK
ITEM_ATTR_ID - FK
ITEM_ATTR_VALUE - STRING

ITEM_ATTR (Table):
ITEM_ATTR_ID - PK
ITEM_ATTR_NAME - STRING
```

Each `Item` can have multiple attributes in `Item_master_attr` table. 
Each `Item Attribute name` will be stored in the `Item_Attr` table.

To detail out:

```
Item 1 ----> Attr 1 -----> Attr Name 1
Item 1 ----> Attr 2 -----> Attr Name 2
Item 2 ----> Attr 1 -----> Attr Name 1
```

Any help really appreciable.

---

I created the class now in the same way now but not clear how to set the data while doing a create operation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_attributes")
public class ItemAttributeDTO implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4678662910814121175L;
    private int itemAttributeID;
    private String itemAttrName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "itemAttributeMapDTO")
    private Collection<ItemAttributeMapDTO> itemAttributeMap = new ArrayList<ItemAttributeMapDTO>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ITEM_ATTR_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getItemAttributeID() {
        return itemAttributeID;
    }

    public void setItemAttributeID(int itemAttributeID) {
        this.itemAttributeID = itemAttributeID;
    }

    @Column(name = "ATTR_NAME")
    public String getItemAttrName() {
        return itemAttrName;
    }

    public void setItemAttrName(String itemAttrName) {
        this.itemAttrName = itemAttrName;
    }

    public Collection<ItemAttributeMapDTO> getItemAttributeMap() {
        return itemAttributeMap;
    }

    public void setItemAttributeMap(
            Collection<ItemAttributeMapDTO> itemAttributeMap) {
        this.itemAttributeMap = itemAttributeMap;
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "item_master")
public class ItemMasterDTO implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4678662910814121175L;
    private int itemID;
    private int locationId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "itemMasterDTO", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<ItemAttributeDTO> itemAttributeDTO = new ArrayList<ItemAttributeDTO>();

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ITEM_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getItemID() {
        return itemID;
    }

    public void setItemID(int itemID) {
        this.itemID = itemID;
    }

    @Column(name = "LOCATION_ID")
    public int getLocationId() {
        return locationId;
    }

    public void setLocationId(int locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

    public Collection<ItemAttributeDTO> getItemAttributeDTO() {
        return itemAttributeDTO;
    }

    public void setItemAttributeDTO(
            Collection<ItemAttributeDTO> itemAttributeDTO) {
        this.itemAttributeDTO = itemAttributeDTO;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM_MASTER_ATTRIBUTES")
public class ItemAttributeMapDTO {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID")
    private ItemMasterDTO itemMasterDTO;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ATTR_ID")
    private ItemAttributeDTO itemAttributeDTO;

    private int item_master_id;

    public ItemMasterDTO getItemMasterDTO() {
        return itemMasterDTO;
    }

    public void setItemMasterDTO(ItemMasterDTO itemMasterDTO) {
        this.itemMasterDTO = itemMasterDTO;
    }

    public ItemAttributeDTO getItemAttributeDTO() {
        return itemAttributeDTO;
    }

    public void setItemAttributeDTO(ItemAttributeDTO itemAttributeDTO) {
        this.itemAttributeDTO = itemAttributeDTO;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ITEM_MASTER_ATTRIBUTE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getItem_master_id() {
        return item_master_id;
    }

    public void setItem_master_id(int item_master_id) {
        this.item_master_id = item_master_id;
    }

}


    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();


            //Set the Item Master
            ItemMasterDTO itmDto = new ItemMasterDTO();
            itmDto.setLocationId(100);

            //Set the Item Attributes
            ItemAttributeDTO itmAttDto = new ItemAttributeDTO();

            ????.......
```

Comment: check the onetomany annotation http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Comment: onetomany we can map 2 tables. But how I can do a map Item_master_attr back to Item_attr. Can you be more specific.

Comment: just posted an answer, check if that can keep you

Comment: just posted an answer, check if that can help* you

Comment: I updated as per your suggestion. Can you help me now on how to set the data while create operation. I will have predefined data ITEM_ATTR table. So during creation operation I need to insert 1 record in the master table and need to pull the Item_Attr Id based on the Attr Name and then I need to map the Item with multiple Attrs in Mapping table. Hope you understand the scenario now.

Comment: that is a whole new question based on your initial one... the correct thing would be for you to post a new one based in the problems you faced after the solution you got from this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example of how your class could look like if you use hibernate annotations:

ITEM_MASTER_ATT class - annotate a ManyToOne based in the foreign key

```
@Entity
public class ITEM_MASTER_ATTR {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID")
    private ITEM_MASTER itemMaster;   

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ATTR_ID")
    private ITEM_ATTR itemAttr;   

}
```

ITEM_MASTER class - annotate a OneToMany based in the inverse, using the mappedBy field.

```
@Entity
public class ITEM_MASTER {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "itemMaster")
    private Collection<ITEM_MASTER_ATTR> masterAttr = new    ArrayList<ITEM_MASTER_ATTR>();

}
```

ITEM_ATTR class annotate a OneToMany based in the inverse, using the mappedBy field.

```
@Entity
public class ITEM_ATTR {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "itemAttr")
    private Collection<ITEM_MASTER_ATTR> masterAttr = new    ArrayList<ITEM_MASTER_ATTR>();

}
```